# Spring 3 Autowired BeanInitializationException

Tags: spring, autowired, required

I have a big problem with @Autowired that always return with exception

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'serviceFactory' is required for bean 'A'

Here are the brief of everything (I am using Spring 3.2 and I have put all the jar in the right place WEB-INF/lib).

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sc" />

<!-- Comment out - we are going to use @Component @Autowired - 2014-01-07
<bean id="A" class="com.sc.A">
  <property name="serviceFactory" ref="serviceFactoryBean" />
</bean> 
-->

<bean id="serviceFactoryBean" class="com.sc.ServiceFactory" autowire="byName" />

</beans>
```

Content of Class com.sc.A

```
@Component
public class A
{

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(A.class);

// @Autowired -- 2014-01-07 comment out as not need it since annotation in setter below
// @Qualifier("serviceFactoryBean")
private ServiceFactory serviceFactory;

public A()
{ }

@Autowired // add 2014-01-07
@Required
public void setServiceFactory(ServiceFactory serviceFactory)
{
  this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
}

public boolean checkSomething() 
{
  if(this.serviceFactory == null)
   logger.error("serviceFactory is null. Autowired failed");

 // do something
}


} // end of class A
```

Content of class com.sc.ServiceFactory

```
// @Component -- comment out 2014-01-07
public class ServiceFactory
{
  // do whatever
}
```

then I compiled the classes and ran it in jetty and when jetty went up, It always throw up long exception of

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'A' defined in URL ... Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'serviceFactory' is required for bean 'A'

I have try many combination with and without annotation to no avail. It is very frustrating to face this error.

Please help

Comment: Do you have getter/setter for serviceFactory within your A-class? Also you mix something. If you use @Autowired, you don't need to define the beans in your xml at all

Comment: yes I have get and set in A-class for serviceFactory.

Comment: I'm not sure, but remove `autowire="byName"` and see if it works or not. By the way `@Required` is not needed at all, `@Autowired` has a parameter for it and its default value is `required=true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things wrong (or rather misunderstood) in your question.

With your current context, you are declaring two bean definitions for each of `A` and `ServiceFactory`. One implicitly from the `@Component` annotation and `<component-scan>` and another from the explicit `<bean>` declarations. Choose one or the other or you might find yourself in a position where Spring doesn't know which to use.

With the above, what happens is that Spring tries to generate an `A` bean because of its `@Component` annotation and sees `@Required` on the `setServiceFactory()` method, but doesn't know what to do with it. `@Required`'s javadoc states

> Marks a method (typically a JavaBean setter method) as being
>   'required': that is, **the setter method must be configured to be
>   dependency-injected with a value.**

But in your case, it isn't. Add `@Autowired` to it.

```
@Required
@Autowired
public void setServiceFactory(ServiceFactory serviceFactory) {
    this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
}
```

Now Spring will know what to do with that method, ie. inject a `ServiceFactory` bean.

Comment: I have decided to use annotation in class A - so I take it out (comment out) from applicationContext.xml. I deleted @Component from ServiceFactory thus ServiceFactory only relies on applicationContext. I put Autowired as you suggested and it still does not work.

Comment: @Spring Can you edit your question and add what exception it gives you now?

Comment: @Spring Note that you already have `@Autowired` on the field, you don't need it on both the setter and field.

Comment: I modify the code to disable all autowired and qualify bean in the declaration part. I get NullPointerException now as serviceFactory has null in it. Though I read the log (I set springframework to DEBUG level) and it shows that Spring container aware of the Autowired, Required and so on. However when I want to use serviceFactory in class A - serviceFactory is not set to something. It is still null

Comment: @Spring Your code, as it currently stands, works for me. Just revert it to what you have in your question.

Comment: You got it right. I use new operator to call class A in the other class thus the class A is generated newly without calling the applicationContext (NullPointerException as result).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution.

The below did work for me after couple of days struggle. I was trying either with Required or with Autowired as per the Spring documentation, and it was not work

@Required
@Autowired